# How do you create a new performance level in Nvidia powermizer?

Tags: nvidia, overclocking

I would like to overclock my Nvidia GT 710 GPU.  I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

The GreenWithEnvy (GWE) utility said I need to set coolbits to 8 to overclock. I found tutorials online explaining how to do this, but I received the error: `Error applying overclock!`

[image: screenshot of error]

Then I tried overclocking using powermizer, but received the following error:

[image: screenshot of text]

Then I resorted to using the GUI interface. Changing the numbers had no effect and reset to zero after I closed `nvidia-settings`.

Then I found out that changing performance levels does work, however I can't figure out how to create a new performance level.

Comment: It's difficult to determine you what you might be doing wrong if your descriptions of what you've already done are not clear.  I suggest that you edit your question and include clearer details about what you've already tried.  For example, "I tried overclocking using powermizer" doesn't actually give us any details about what you actually did. Similarly, telling us that you found a tutorial isn't useful unless you provide a link to said tutorial along with a clear description of what exactly you did.

Answer (score 1):

This method (via CLI) is no longer supported by NVIDIA drivers.
You could try setting coolbits to 31 and also testing TuxClocker. I think minimum of "coolbits 12" is required for fan and GPU/Mem clock control in general.